# React: How to loop through Array of Objects in MongoDb

Tags: reactjs, arrays, mongodb

i want to go through an Array of Objects in MongoDB
[(for Schema look at the picture.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZT3u.png)

I want to check if the User is participant of an Event and if, the event should be displayed on a page .

My idea was

```
{events.filter(events => ( events.participants.email === currentProfile.email)).
               map((events)=>(
                 <Grid key={events._id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                 <Event event={events} setCurrentId2={setCurrentId2} />
```

but does not work. I dont have any idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`events.participants` is an array and you are doing `events.participants.email` wich is undefined, to do what you want:

```
{events
        .filter((e) => e.participants.some((p) => p.email === currentProfile.email))
        .map((event) => (
          <>
            <Grid key={event._id} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
            <Event event={event} setCurrentId2={setCurrentId2} />
          <>
        ))}
```

With this, each event is iterating the partcipants field looking for the current user's email